# How to run a method at a date which comes from DB

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I work on an EF .Net Core project.
I want to notify when time is came. For example, there is a endDate of a campaign and you need to send an e-mail to notify ending situation. I have no idea how to do this? Have you any solution or advice to learn? 
Thanks.

Comment: If I understand you need check date in interval and run any task? I am using Hangfire for that. https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: Or look at Quartz.Net. If you want to know how to use it in ASP.Net Core so read this [article](https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-quartz-net-hosted-service-with-asp-net-core/).

Comment: Hangfire, Azure WebJobs,

Comment: Just use a hosted service, which for this scenario, you can base on the timed example provided in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. I'm going to check them all.